# Add unique color watermark per frame with FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been able to add a random color watermark with this code:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 100 -i "N%3d.tif" -c:v libx264 -vf "drawbox=y=0:color=random@1:width=8:height=ih:t=fill,scale=1920:1080" -crf 30 -g 10 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

And I know that it's doable with a script and processing each input frame individually, but I would really like to find a way with FFMpeg to add the watermark during the actual video encoding. It needs to be a unique color per frame. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawbox expression is only evaluated once. But the [hue](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue) filter can be used to vary the color.

In the command below, a small portion from the left side of the frame is cropped off, a color is drawn once, and then its hue varied. This is then overlaid on the full frame.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 100 -i "N%3d.tif"
       -filter_complex "[0]split=2[wm][vid];[wm]crop=8:ih,drawbox=color=random@1:t=fill,
                           hue=n*random(1234)[wm];[vid][wm]overlay,scale=1920:1080" 
       -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -g 10 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. One hopefully quick question on top - Can you think of a way have the watermark pad / squish the frame instead of crop? I know how to pad two edges, but haven't figured out how to squish only one edge (and yes, disrupting the aspect ratio intentionally).

Comment: Replace `overlay` with `hstack` in the cmd.

Comment: Nice! I will give that a try now. 

Another question - I tested the hue overlay and it appears that it isn't able to draw a uniform color, even with lossless (crf = 0) h264 encoding. The right half appears to have some form of gradient. Any idea on how to avoid that?

Here's a demo - https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0272y3wh7wj1ja/gradient.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I guess I may just be seeing h264 encoding artifacts. Disabling deblocking seems to help a little, but can you think of any way to get close to / ensure this region maintains its true color (ie. maybe some sort of masking)?

Comment: Maybe I could improve its accuracy by adding ~16pixels of black between the image data and color watermark column. Is there an easy way to do that? And also, I'm sure it's simple, but how do you get the watermark on the other side of the video? Thanks again!

Comment: Switch the order of the inputs to hstack

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. And I figured out how to add black padding by adding another video split and stacking all three. Thanks again!

Comment: You can pad video directly. Just use pad filter on one of the inputs.

Comment: Last question I swear - It appears that during the RGB->YUV conversion (with 16-235 video levels) I'm losing some of my unique colors. Here's the sanity check I'm using: `ffmpeg -y -framerate 100 -i "Frame%3d.png" -vf "drawbox=color=red@1:t=fill, hue=h=n,scale=1920:1080" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4`

Can you think of any way to ensure that the colors are going to be discrete in YUV colorspace?

Comment: * I should note that I'm only looking for max 360 unique colors.

Comment: Convert to YUV beforehand and check: `format=yuv444p,drawbox=...`

Comment: I haven't tried converting to YUV beforehand, but even this command isn't able to produce unique colored frames: `fmpeg -y -framerate 1 -i "Frame%3d.png" -vf "drawbox=color=red@1:t=fill, hue=h=n,scale=1920:1080" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -g 1  -pix_fmt yuvj444p out.mp4` - I'm sure it's possible to modulate the S and B components of the hue filter to get enough level separation, but the fact that the command above doesn't work makes me a little suspect of what's going on underneath. Do you see any alternative ways to get ffmpeg to generate unique colors?

Comment: Unique colors is tricky since the filter has to track that no generated color has been used earlier, and in general, filters don't have generic memory store for that. One possible workaround is to not generate colors (completely) using a random seed but to make each successive color differ from the last one with a partially random and partially deterministic expr. This won't guarantee uniqueness across the video but should come close.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I was actually able to get enough separation using the geq filter with RGB values. I could have probably done it with hue, but the math was a little easier for me with RGB.